# How to do this kind of search in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, predicate

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application.

The SQL table has one column `ProdNum` and it contains data such as `4892-34-456-2311`.

The user needs a form to search the database that includes this field.

The problem is that the user wants to have 4 separate fields in the UI razor view whereas each field should match with the 4 parts of data above between `-`.

For example `ProdNum1`, `ProdNum2`, `ProdNum3` and `ProdNum4` field should match with `4892`, `34`, `456`, `2311`.

Since the entire search form contains many fields including these 4 fields, the search logic is based on a predicate which is inherited from the `PredicateBuilder` class.

Something like this:

```
...other field to be filtered

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProdNum1) {
    predicate = predicate.And(
        t => t.ProdNum.toString().Split('-')[0].Contains(ProdNum1).ToList();

...other fields to be filtered
```

But the above code has run-time error:

> The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities`

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Poorly written and formatted question. Almost unreadable.

Comment: This means accessing data via index (see `[0]`) is not supported when translating your expression to SQL. Try something like `.Split('-').FirstOrDefault().Contains(ProdNum1)`. I'm not sure whether `Split()` is supported.

Comment: Sorry, please let me know if you have any question for this poorly written question, much appreciated!

Comment: After trying, this is not working, I got error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. it seems the Split is not supported.

Comment: @user2949042 ...as expected. Is the `-` character always at a fixed position? Btw: you can find all supported functions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/string-canonical-functions

Comment: Please review the edit so that i can edit the qs properly

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, yes, that format is fixed, it is always saved like that format. I need to find similar method the separate the happens ('-'), basically get each part of data and compare with each field from UI and combine with other filtered fields

Comment: If the position is fixed then use a combination of `IndexOf('-')` and `Substring()` to get the number sequence.

Comment: @zack raiyan, thanks a lot for your editing, it looks great, much appreciated!

Comment: @zackraiyan FYI, I incorporated your chances into my edit.

Comment: It was not my edit tho .......But i am osting an answer,please be patient

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, thanks a lot for your quick response, it seems the index and substring can not be used together. predicate.And(t => t.ProdNum.ToString().IndexOf('-') does not recongnize SubString() after it.

Comment: By the way, I use predicateBuilder class to filer as this example: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all responses, finally, I found an easy way to resolve it.
instead of rebuilding models and change the database tables, I just add extra space in the search strings to match the search criteria. since the data format always is: 4892-34-456-2311, so I use Startwith(PODNum1) to search first field, and use Contains("-" + PODNum2 + "-") to search second and third strings (replace PODNum1 to PODNum3), and use EndWith("-" + PODNum4) to search 4th string. This way, I don't need to change anything else, it is simple. 
Again, thanks a lot for all responses, much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, this should work but has a disadvantage: the user needs to input the full string part to get a match.

Comment: yes, but to avoid that, I added a javascript validation to force user to enter the exact same number of digits in each 4 number fields, they can not enter 3 integer in first part which requires 4 integers. and plus using StartsWith and EndWith with ''-" combinations, so really, I create a unique search string, user does not need to input full string to get a match, please let me know if this is OK,

Comment: If it fits your needs then it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correct,you have one column which u want to act like 4 different column ? This isn't worth it...For that,you need to `Split` each rows column data,create a class to handle the splitted data and finally use a `List .Thats a useless workaround.I rather suggest u to use 4 columns instead.

But if you still want to go with your existing applied method,you first need to `Split` as i mentioned earlier.For that,here's an example :

```
  public void test()
{
SqlDataReader datareader = new SqlDataReader;
while (datareader.read)
{
    string part1 = datareader(1).toString.Split("-")(0);///the 1st part of your column data
    string part2 = datareader(1).toString.Split("-")(1);///the 2nd part of your column data
}
}
```

Now,as mentioned in the comments,you can rather a class to handle all the data.For example,let's call it mydata

```
public class mydata {

public string part1;

public string part2;

public string part3;

public string part4;
}
```

Now,within the `While` loop of the `SqlDatareader`,declare a new instance of this class and pass the values to it.An example :

```
public void test()
{
SqlDataReader datareader = new SqlDataReader;
while (datareader.read)
{
    Mydata alldata = new Mydata;
    alldata.Part1 = datareader(1).toString.Split("-")(0);
    alldata.Part2 = datareader(1).toString.Split("-")(1);
}
}
```

Create a list of the class in class-level

```
public class MyForm
{
List<MyData> storedData = new List<MyData>;
}
```

Within the while loop of the `SqlDatareader`,add this at the end :

```
 storedData.Add(allData);
```

So finally, u have a list of all the splitted data..So write your filtering logic easily :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, zack raiyan, I agree, ideally, the database table should have 4 columns associated with 4 UI fields, but since the database table has built and we do not want to change the table structure. I just want to find a simple way to achieve this kind search as I explored it. Your example codes need more model changes, it may impact a lot other models, I will try to find if there is any other easy way, thanks a lot any way,

Comment: This is the easiest way,you want me to provide a full example ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your offering, let's wait to see if there is any easiest way, thanks again.

Comment: U git many downvotes,don't if your qs will be answered by anyone :(

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in a comment, the error means that  accessing data via index (see `[0]`) is not supported when translating your expression to SQL. `Split('-')` is also not supported hence you have to resort to the supported functions  `Substring()` and `IndexOf(startIndex)`.

You could do something like the following to first transform the string into 4 *number strings* ...

```
.Select(t => new {
    t.ProdNum,
    FirstNumber = t.ProdNum.Substring(0, t.ProdNum.IndexOf("-")),
    Remainder = t.ProdNum.Substring(t.ProdNum.IndexOf("-") + 1)
})
.Select(t => new {
    t.ProdNum,
    t.FirstNumber,
    SecondNumber = t.Remainder.Substring(0, t.Remainder.IndexOf("-")),
    Remainder = t.Remainder.Substring(t.Remainder.IndexOf("-") + 1)
})
.Select(t => new {
    t.ProdNum,
    t.FirstNumber,
    t.SecondNumber,
    ThirdNumber = t.Remainder.Substring(0, t.Remainder.IndexOf("-")),
    FourthNumber = t.Remainder.Substring(t.Remainder.IndexOf("-") + 1)
})
```

... and then you could simply write something like

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProdNum3) {
    predicate = predicate.And(
        t => t.ThirdNumber.Contains(ProdNum3)
```

Comment: Hi ViRuSTriNiTy, thanks a lot for your help, the select statement is very interesting, but it doesn't use the new 4 fields from UI and still needs extra conditions as user may enter data in one of 4 fields, so any field can be blank. Also, user may also enter 3 numbers to fields which allows 2 or 4 numbers vise versa. so I will go with my own solution as it is simpler, and also add validation in razor view. Any way, thanks a lot for your help,